# How to deploy jQuery mobile app on the Android phone - PhoneGap isn't working

Tags: jquery-mobile

I was wondering how to deploy jQuery mobile app on the Android phone. For some reason PhoneGap isn't loading on my PC, even though I have the correct version installed. What are the other ways that I can deploy it?

Thank you for your feedback!

Answer (score 0):

In that case

1. create zip of your code then go to https://build.phonegap.com/
2. Scroll down to choose your plan section
3. Select free plan
4. sign-in with your adobe ID or create one if you don't have one.
5. Select private and click on upload zip file.
6. select your zip
7. Fill out app name and Description (optional).
8. and click on "Ready to build" button
9. Wait for a while, phonegap build will you package files for all platforms like android,BlackBerry,Windows etc...

Basically what it does is, it provides cloud based build system.

*Do consider the file size limit. Your zip file should not be greater than 15MB*